# Unity3d Problema en seleccionar los vectores3 que tengan una determinada posicion en z

Tags: unity3d

Me estoy volviendo loco con algo que debería ser fácil en principio.

Tengo una lista de `Vector3` y quiero seleccionar solo los que la posición Z sea igual a 1.0.

La lista esta en otra clase y es la:

```
 tableroScript.GetComponent<Tablero>().listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar
```

(Eso no es problema ya que he comprobado que me la encuentra.)

El código que estoy usando es:

```
public void QuitarVectoresParaNoPonerFicha(){

        //Se configura cada escena de forma independiente
        //if (nombreDeLAEscena == "1Scena(1)") {

        for (int a = 0; a < tableroScript.GetComponent<Tablero> ().listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar.Count; a++) {

            if (tableroScript.GetComponent<Tablero> ().listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [a] !=null) {

                print ("EstamosRevisandoElVector3= " + tableroScript.GetComponent<Tablero> ().listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [a]);

        //EN ESTA LINEA DE ABAJO DEBERIA ENCONTRAR TODAS LAS POSICIONES Z

                if (tableroScript.GetComponent<Tablero> ().listaPosicionesFichasParaBarajar [a] .z ==  1.0f) {

                    print("Esta en z 1.0");

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Y no me los encuentra. No se que estoy haciendo mal.